Defining a Notebook vs Estimator instance on AWS SageMaker
When I launch a notebook in SageMaker, I am asked which instance I would like to run it on.
When I define my estimator I also define an instance:
estimator = PyTorch(
    entry_point="script.py",
    base_job_name='training_job',
    role=role,
    framework_version="1.4.0",
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
    py_version='py3'
)

How I understand it is that my Notebook instance can be very light as it is just providing the resources to run the notebook cells, whereas the estimator is doing the heavy lifting, and this is where I should define a stronger instance. Is this understanding correct?

Yes, your understanding is correct.
Your notebook can run on a small instance, while the training job can run on a larger instance.
The training job instance is provisioned when you call Estimator.fit(). Based on your estimator definition, the specified instances will be provisioned and terminated automatically after the training is done.
For example, your notebook might use a ml.t3.medium instance, while the training job could use one or multiple ml.g5.4xlarge instances.
This allows your notebook to use a small CPU instance while still leveraging GPU-enabled instances for training, which are terminated automatically after completion.
